# What's the difference between elastic, fluid, liquid, fixed layout in CSS

Tags: css, layout

What's the difference between elastic, fluid, liquid, fixed layout in CSS. Are there any other types?

Comment: There's fixed, not fixed, scaling, and mixtures of each.

Comment: Note: elastic layouts are becoming obsolete, as modern browsers now just zoom in the entire page, rather than resizing the text specifically.

Comment: The links of the accepted answer are now dead or unrelated to the question. [What is the differenence between Fixed vs. Fluid vs. Elastic Layout vs Responsive layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482518/what-is-the-differenence-between-fixed-vs-fluid-vs-elastic-layout-vs-responsiv) is a newer duplicate with a complete answer.